include a single pre-commit-config file in many repos
I'm starting to use pre-commit, and I have a single repository with a pre-commit-config.yaml file that I want all the other (many more) repositories to simply 'include'. Is there a way to do that?
The ideal solution would be something like this:
// pre-commit-config.yaml in repo 'A'
include config from <single-repo-url>


there is intentionally no such "include" mechanism for pre-commit configurations.
each repository tends to have some customization needed (on top of a theoretical "base" configuration) and as such an include mechanism would tend to reduce flexibility instead of increasing convenience.
pre-commit already provides reusable repositories which is where the bulk of the complexity lies
there are hacky workarounds some have come up with in the issue tracker (such as utilizing a hook which itself calls pre-commit --config ... in a nested manner) but these are not encouraged

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Thanks! Although I'm wondering, why does that reduce your flexibility? For example, in GitLab CI/CD, you can easily include jobs from other repositories. You can then customize your own repository if you don't want the base jobs by overriding them, or by extending them and overriding only specific attributes. I would think it should be the same here. Unfortunately, the situation here is that if I don't use the command you suggested, a small change as updating a hook for a certain version is going to take a while. The current approach is great if you have few repos, but I guess not for my case

"by overriding them" -- that's exactly what the config lets you do.  "a small change as updating a hook" -- try using something like all-repos or set up pre-commit ci (disclaimer I wrote both of those as well).  I have hundreds of repos and it's not an issue

If I correctly understand your question, you need to create a .pre-commit-config.yaml file in each repository where you want to use this pre-commit configuration.
The file should look like this:
repos:
 - repo: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/pre-commit
    rev: v0.1.17
    hooks:
      - id: terraform-fmt


repo should point to your repository containing the pre-commit hooks;

rev specifies the version. You can use a Git tag, or a specific Git commit hash;

hooks:id this is an id (like name) of specific hook within your repository;


You can find all available parameters in the documentation
And here’s an example repository: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/pre-commit
And of course in each repo you need to do the following:

Install pre-commit. E.g. brew install pre-commit.
Run pre-commit install in the repo.

Alternatively, instead of using pre-commit, you might find it more suitable to use a Git template along with Git hooks, such as prepare-commit-msg.
In that case you can check my repo with examples, which could serve as a good starting point.
The only downside is that you'll need to set the environment variable GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR which point to git-template, and run git int command every time after you updated git-template repo.

Hey, thanks for the answer. The problem I have is that, let's say I have 40 repositories. I don't want each of them to have its own .pre-commit-config.yaml file, as they are all the same. Instead, I want each of them to simply 'include' a single pre-commit-config.yaml file that contains all the definitions you described. This way, if I need to make changes to the YAML file, I only have to update it in one place.

i'm not sure that this is possible to do like you say. But if you need to setup it only locally, for you, you can place .pre-commit-config.yaml file to specific folder (/opt/ for example), and add a symlink to that file from all other repos. I tested it right now and all works as expected:
ls -la 
.pre-commit-config.yaml -> /opt/.pre-commit-config.yaml


also, i added one more alternative approach with using git hooks and git templates.
